# connect to oracle 7.3.4 hp_ux1020 on windows 7

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration, oracle7

i just joined a company and they have a hp_ux1020 that has oracle 7.3.4 on it. they now want to convert that to sql. i have windows 7 have no idea how or what to use to connect to that server remotely. I know nothing about linux. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle 7 is an incredibly old version long out of support.
Converting a database is not a small task, depending on the complexity of the database, but is doable.
Depending on your experience, it may be best to hire a contractor that specializes in database migrations.
I suggest creating CSV (comma-separated values) files for each table and, from those, importing into your new Microsoft SQL Server database.

No modern client connects to Oracle 7, but it may be worth a try to use the oldest downloadable version of Oracle SQL Developer (1.3x I think). Oracle SQL Developer connects to Oracle 8 with an unsupported version warning, but I have not tested with 7.

You may have to go on a hunt to find a client old enough to connect to 7. Oracle typically does not provide clients for unsupported version of Oracle, even though they have all the necessary files.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i'm asking to see if i can use latest oracle client or toad to connect to it? or what version of oracle client, toad do i need to use to connect to the database.

Comment: I have updated my answer to offer what information I do have, though I have no access to Oracle versions older than 8.